# How to disable :hover on descendants?

Tags: html, css

**Link:**
http://jsbin.com/EFAlace/3/edit?html,css,output

**HTML:**

```
 <a href='#' class='tooltip-parent'>Hover over me!
    <span class='tooltip-container'>
    <span class='tooltip'>
      <a style='href='#'>Weird link</a><br>
      One<br>
      Two<br> 
      Three<br>
      Four<br>
    </span>
    </span>

</a>
```

*`.tooltip-container` added for absolute positioning, for 'reset' tooltip position.*

**CSS (LESS):**

```
.tooltip-container {
position: absolute;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.tooltip-parent {
  display: inline-block;
  .tooltip {
    width: 150px;
    display: none;
    position:relative;

    border:1px solid blue;
    &:before, &:after {
      content: '';
      top: -20px;
      left: 20%;
      position: absolute;

      border-left: 20px solid transparent;
      border-right: 20px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 20px solid white;
      margin-left: -20px;
    }   
    &:before {
      border-left: 23px solid transparent;
    border-right: 23px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 23px solid;
      margin-left: -23px;

    border-bottom-color: inherit; /* Can't be included in the shorthand to work */
    top: -23px;      
    }

  }
  &:hover .tooltip {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;  
    top: 20px;  
  }
}
ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0; padding:0;
  li {margin: 0; padding:0;}
}
```

**`:before` and `:after:` things are for triangle at the top of the tooltip. Google on 'CSS triangle pseudo elements'**

I have been experimenting with CSS-only tooltip, which pops out on hover over a parent element. You can see working example at jsBin. But I encountered the strange issue - when I add anchor inside tooltip - html markup blows out, just uncomment this code `<!--<a style='href='#'>Weird link</a><br>-->` in HTML pane and you will see what Im talking about. And then see at markup structure - browser just places HTML content of `.tooltip` outside of and element to which that tooltip is attached.

Thats pretty unclear behavior, any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Always post your code here, just post the relevant parts.

Comment: i would recommend not putting the span with the dropdown content inside the <a> element. Because 1. It's messy as you see. 2. semantically it's wrong since the content of the dropdown isn't supposed to be a link to href of the anchor element.

Comment: your html is invalid, you cannot have a anchor tag inside another anchor tag

Comment: Yep, that is the anchor inside anchor issue.

Comment: HTML doesn't allow an anchor to be inside another anchor.

Answer (score 0):

first i see a problem of anchor inside anchor, that's not allowed by html. try to rearrange your html tags in a better way.

secondly about the weird link, which is:

```
<a style='href='#'>Weird link</a>
```

why is it

```
style='href='#'
```